# python-xarray: Compute the absolute values of a dataset

Tags: python-xarray, numpy-ufunc

`np.fabs` works fine on `xr.DataArray`'s but not `xr.Dataset`'s.

```
data = xr.DataArray(np.random.randn(2, 3), coords={'x': ['a', 'b']}, dims=('x', 'y'))
ds = xr.Dataset({'foo': data, 'bar': ('x', [1, 2]), 'baz': np.pi})
np.fabs(ds)
TypeError: ufunc 'fabs' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
np.fabs(ds['foo'])
<xarray.DataArray 'foo' (x: 2, y: 3)>
array([[ 0.384305,  0.161676,  0.07573 ],
       [ 0.789885,  1.299188,  1.965528]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) <U1 'a' 'b'
Dimensions without coordinates: y
```

Any ideas how to apply it to a `xr.Dataset`?

I could just loop over the variables in the `xr.Dataset` (see below) but i'm not sure if there is something more efficient

```
for i, var in enumerate(ds.data_vars):
    ds[var] = np.fabs(ds[var])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to use do is to use Python's builtin `abs()` function: `abs(ds)` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `apply` method on the `Dataset`.

```
In [10]: ds.apply(np.fabs)
Out[10]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (x: 2, y: 3)
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) <U1 'a' 'b'
Dimensions without coordinates: y
Data variables:
    foo      (x, y) float64 0.2069 2.685 1.815 1.674 1.038 0.5664
    baz      float64 3.142
    bar      (x) float64 1.0 2.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. From reading http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.apply.html#xarray.Dataset.apply 'Apply a function over the data variables in this dataset.' That totally makes sense. Apologies I didn't pick this up.